# Flexbox: Is there a way to specify equal column widths with a variable amount of columns?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
div.column-container {
  display: flex;
}

div.column-container section {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

section:nth-child(1) {
  background: tomato;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
  background: aqua;
}

section:nth-child(3) {
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-container">
  <section>
    <div>
      <h2>Learn about the this</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div>
      <h2>Ask the right questions</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div>
      <h2>Download a guide with a long description</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I know we can explicitly define a width using:

`flex: 1 1 33%;`

but I was just wondering if there was a way to tell flexbox to make all columns of equal width since, as I understand, flexbox elements are aware of it's siblings' dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to spray evenly elements on a row, **you only need** to set `1` to `flex`;

```css
div.column-container {
  display: flex;
}

div.column-container section {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 ;/* share evenly space */
  padding: 20px;
}

section:nth-child(1), section:nth-child(4) {
  background: tomato;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
  background: aqua;
}

section:nth-child(3) {
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-container">
  <section>
    <div>
      <h2>Learn about the this</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div>
      <h2>Ask the right questions</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div>
      <h2>Download a guide with a long description</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<div class="column-container">
  <section>
    <div>
      <h2>Learn about the this</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div>
      <h2>Ask the right questions</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div>
      <h2>Download a guide with a long description</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div>
      <h2>Learn about the this</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.column-container {
  display: flex;
}

div.column-container section {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

section:nth-child(1) {
  background: tomato;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
  background: aqua;
}

section:nth-child(3) {
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-container">
  <section>
    <div>
      <h2>Learn about the this</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div>
      <h2>Ask the right questions</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div>
      <h2>Download a guide with a long description</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

The solution was to use `flex: 1 1 0` instead of `flex: 1 1 auto`.